# ServiceStack Dictionary DTO Dictionary<string, string> Data type deserialization

Tags: servicestack

An object with one of the member's data type Dictionary is being retrieved as null when sending through JSON

I've created a DTO with the following schema

```
public class myclass
{
  public string APIKey {get;set;}
  public string APISecret {get;set;}
  public string APIVersion {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<string,string> Fields {get;set;}
}
```

I've tried to send JSON to my API by using below JS

```
  $.ajax({

      type: "GET",

      dataType: "jsonp",

      url: $('#txtUrl').val(),

      data: {APIKey:"test",APISecret:"test", APIVersion:"1.0",Fields:[{"Key":"JobID","Value":"2290277"},{"Key":"CountryID","Value":"1"}]},

      success: function (data) {



                       // Now the two will work

                       $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                              if (key == 'Fields')

                              {                                                     

                                     $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {

                                            $('#result').append('<br />' + key2 + ' ' + value2);

                                     });

                              }

                              else

                                     $('#result').append('<br />' + key + ' ' + value);

                       });







        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to modify my jScript

{"APIKey":"test","APISecret":"test","APIVersion":"1.0",
"Fields":**"**{'JobID':'2290277','CountryID':'1'}**"**}

Answer (score 3):

Your json should be formatted like this. Don't use Value and Keys property names. Also put your property names in quotes.

```
{"APIKey":"test","APISecret":"test","APIVersion":"1.0",
"Fields":{"JobID":"2290277","CountryID":"1"}}
```

Whenever I run into these problems I run some simple code to see how the ServiceStack Serializer expects the json to be formatted:

```
var m = new myclass();
m.APIKey = "test";
m.APISecret = "test";
m.APIVersion = "1.0";
m.Fields =new Dictionary<string, string>();
m.Fields.Add("JobID", "2290277");
m.Fields.Add("CountryID", "1");
string json = m.ToJson();
```

Then compare that to your own json.

Comment: I fixed the issue with different way. Need to modify the JScript to be like {"APIKey":"test","APISecret":"test","APIVersion":"1.0",
"Fields":"{'JobID':'2290277','CountryID':'1'}"}. See the difference?Double quote in the Fields Value

Comment: You don't need to mess with double and single quotes. Its simpler to use the curly braces for objects. See http://www.json.org/ for json spec.